# Restoring backup from CWM recovery

Tags: backup, rom, restore, clockworkmod-recovery

I made a backup of my stock ROM before flashing a Custom ROM. I used CWM recovery. But that backup wasn't fully  made due to memory constraints. But still it created files worth 1.01 GB in the backup folder. There are 4 files in that backup -

- boot.img (6 MB),
- data.ext4.tar (577 MB)
- recovery.img (6 MB),
- system.ext4.tar (448 MB).

My question is, if I try to restore from this backup, will it work?

Comment: There's no way to know, those zips could be incomplete. The only way to know is to try, but my guess is that it will not work. It needs to be the complete image. Very unlikely.

Comment: @RossC I have tried opening those archives, and they open without error. Otherwise they would have been corrupted, if they were not complete !

Comment: Do you need to restore the entire backup, or do you just want to pick parts of it (e.g. some apps with their data)?

Comment: @Izzy I am concerned with the stock ROM only.

Comment: In that case, it might be a safer approach to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)